# Cannot connect to the Internet, would appreciate some help in diagnosing the problem!

Tags: wireless, internet

So recently, I decided to make the switch from Windows. Installing Ubuntu went smoothly (as far as I can tell), but I can't connect to the internet. The wifi icon is there and when I go to Settings it shows as connected, but when I open Firefox all websites display the "Server Not Found" message. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on an HP laptop.

If there's any more information you need, please ask and I'll try to provide it. I'm not a particularly tech savvy person and would appreciate some advice on how to find the cause of the problem.

Edit: after running the command `nmcli device`, this is the output.

[image: this is the output]

After running the command `nmcli device show wlx2c054725893c`, this is the output.

[image: this is the output]

After running the command `ping 110.242.68.66`, this is the output.

[image: this is the output.]

It continued like this for a while, eventually when I pressed Ctrl-C it ended like this.

[image: this]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you run the command `nmcli device` in the Terminal and post an output image of it?

Comment: Sure, thanks for responding @ArjunKShibu! I don't know how to post images in comments, so I'll edit it in the original post.

Comment: what if you `ping 8.8.8.8`?
and what if you `ping www.google.com`?
what is the output of `nmcli device wlx2c054725893c`?

Comment: @jasmines I live in China where Google is blocked, so it probably wouldn't work anyway. However, I've tried pinging several other websites, they all give the result `Temporary failure in name resolution`. Thank you for the suggestion though!   Edit: apologies, didn't see your edit. It says `Error: argument wlx2c054725893c not understood. Try pasting --help instead.`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the show parameter: `nmcli device show wlx2c054725893c`

Comment: @jasmines ah, thanks! I've edited the results into my post.

Comment: stupid question: do other devices connected to the same wifi navigate correctly?

Comment: Yep, I'm posting from my phone right now!

Comment: ok let's try to ping an IP (ensure it's not blocked in China)

Comment: @jasmines I've edited the post. Really appreciate your taking the time to help me!

Comment: It's strange the ping is working for a while, then it stops, finally it works again. Anyway, you can try to update your /etc/resolv.conf with an alternative DNS server

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to do that? Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to how these things work 